# A good term for "Dead" God

Tags: synonyms, religion

I am doing some world building for my game, but it's not really a world building question. I wouldn't have the problem with this term in my native language, it's strictly about the limits of my English.

In my world the people worship a deity that they believe was killed in ancient times, but should be resurrected again. I am trying to coin a good term how their worship would call it. The "Dead God" doesn't have a reverent sound to it. I was thinking perhaps Deceased (seems formal, rather than religious) or Departed (not necessarily dead) God, or Slain (puts too much emphasis on the nature of killing) God.

I looked for synonyms, but couldn't find anything really fitting well. Maybe there are some archaic terms that would work well? Or maybe I am looking for some other term that would have the right tone and meaning?

Comment: Maybe you can instead focus on the rejuvenation/reincarnation aspect and use some play on the word Phoenix. As a player I might  even be OK associating a word like Incarna with a reincarnating god, though its meaning will  be closer to  in-flesh.

Comment: Dormant, abeyant.

Comment: Wikipedia's [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dying-and-rising_deity) on the concept as described by anthropologist James Frazer uses the terms "dying god" or "dying-and-rising god". However you'd have to judge if this matched the god you describe.

Comment: In British History/Folkloric tradition King Arthur, who some scholars argue has his roots as a celtic god, is sometimes referred to as the 'once and future king', perhaps you can have a Once and Future King.

Comment: It would seem to me that most gods are dead gods. How many are even alive when worshiped? And when they are, they are called a living god.

Comment: For the capitalised word as opposed to 'gods' = 'idols', _contradiction in terms_.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use the term "Old God" which presents an eerie sort of power around this deity's name or persona.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The figurative use of **sleeper** to mean a dead person may help you accomplish both describing a dead god and hinting that the dead god may *awaken*.

The Oxford English Dictionary describes the usage in "sleeper, n.," definition 2a:

> One who is asleep. Also *figurative*, a dead person.

The metaphor of death as a sleep is deep within English literature and culture. For instance, in Shakespeare's play *The Tempest*, Prospero uses the metaphor to describe raising the dead ([Act 5, Scene 1](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/tempest/tempest.5.1.html)):

> ... graves at my command
>
> Have waked their **sleepers**, oped, and let 'em forth
>
> By my so potent art.

There is also Hamlet's famous soliloquy "[To be or not to be,](https://good-death.english.cam.ac.uk/to-die-to-sleep-to-sleep-perchance-to-dream-ay-theres-the-rub/)" which invites sleep as a metaphor for death:

> To die, to **sleep**--
>
> To **sleep**--perchance to dream. Ay, there's the rub!
>
> For in that **sleep of death** what dreams may come
>
> When we have shuffled off this mortal coil,
>
> Must give us pause...

In Alfred Lord Tennyson's poem *Idylls of the King*, Arthur at the final battle describes the dead soldiers in terms of sleep ("[The Passing of Arthur](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Idylls_of_the_King/The_Passing_of_Arthur)"):

> Then spake King Arthur to Sir Bedivere:
>
> 'The sequel of today unsolders all
>
> The goodliest fellowship of famous knights
>
> Whereof this world holds record. Such a **sleep**
>
> They **sleep**--the men I loved.

Incidentally, King Arthur and sometimes his knights are also supposed to be sleeping and not truly dead, as with the 1834 "[Legend of Shewin' Shiels](https://d.lib.rochester.edu/camelot/text/service-legend-of-shewin-shiels)":

> 'Tis gone! he views the crags of Shewin' Shiels,
>
> And recollects the tale of Arthur's knights,
>
> And trembles as he thinks upon the sights
>
> Just vanished in that fair and fairy hall,
>
> The seven green **sleepers** and the magic call!

Finally, English speakers influenced by Christianity might recognize Ephesians 5:14, which sometimes translates sleep as a verb and sometimes uses the noun *sleepers*:

> Wherefore he saith, Awake thou that **sleepest**, and arise from the dead, and Christ shall give thee light. ([KJV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ephesians%205%3A14&version=KJV))

> This is why it is said: “Wake up, **sleeper**, rise from the dead, and Christ will shine on you.” ([NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ephesians%205%3A14&version=NIV))

So a dead god described as **The Sleeper** would be one figuratively expected to awaken at some point.

Answer (score 0):

**defunct** (adj. and n.)

> No longer living, existing, or functioning
>
> *wrote for a magazine that is now defunct* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/defunct)

> *Figurative*. No longer in existence; having ceased its functions;
> dead, extinct.
>
> **the defunct**: the deceased; hence, with plural (rare), one who is dead, a dead person.
>
> 1771   T. Smollett *Humphry Clinker* II. 140   Knavish priests, who
> pretended that the devil could have no power over the defunct, if he
> was interred in holy ground. (OED online)

*Defunct* can leave it to the imagination as to whether the god is actually dead, forgotten, powerless, choosing not to answer prayers, or perhaps even "decommissioned" or "cancelled" by the people :-)

---

> Now, with every **defunct god** hogging the dwindling supply of
> divinity, would they even answer my summons? [Michael Boatman; *Last
> God Standing*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Last_God_Standing/2lg8CgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22defunct%20god%22&pg=PT130&printsec=frontcover) (2014)

> Some prefer an evil **defunct God**, that someone else taught them,
> and passed down by evil dictators. [A. Star; *God is Bipolar*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/God_Is_Bipolar/sNKlDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22defunct%20god%22&pg=PA85&printsec=frontcover)
> (2019)

> The figure is only Apollo, a **defunct god**; and, like the Lycian
> peasants, he is only a sculptural representation, serving as a foil to
> the real King. [James Herbert; *Our Distance from God*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Our_Distance_from_God/NDAlDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22defunct%20god%22&pg=PA44&printsec=frontcover) (2008)